# INDEX & MATCH formula avoiding duplicates

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I got a first sheet with the name and companies of people, I want to import the company names on a second sheet avoiding duplicates.

I've been using the INDEX & MATCH function but I couldn't make it work.

Here's my formula: =IFERROR(INDEX('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990;SMALL(IF('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990<>"";ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990))));ROWS($1:1))))

Comment: First, using INDIRECT() is hardly ever a good solution. If you have a recent version of Excel, the UNIQUE() function may do what you want.

Comment: I tried to use the UNIQUE function but got the same result =UNIQUE(IFERROR(INDEX('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990;SMALL(IF('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990<>"";ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990))));ROWS($1:1)))))

Comment: What happens if you just use =UNIQUE('Liste de contact'!B$2:B$990) in a single cell on the new sheet? UNIQUE() is an array function, so you use it in a single cell and Excel will try and expand the results for you.

Comment: Well guess what, it worked ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: De rien. Glad you are up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much why the UNIQUE() function was added in Excel (together with SORT() and FILTER()).

[image]

Users had been writing their own UDFs, or resorting to the kind of formulae in the question. Microsoft probably had to wait for Excel to better handle array functions I suppose.